# PHP arrays: If I skip pointers, do they occupy RAM

Tags: php, arrays, size, ram

Given the following example:

```
<?php
$a[7]=0;
$a[1449]=1;
?>
```

How many objects occupy memory? 2 or 1449 objects?

Answer (score 3):

PHP arrays are all associative arrays, even if you use numeric indexes. And they are implemented using a hash table. The number of elements is the smallest power of 2 sufficient to hold all the elements. So there will be space for 2 elements, at this point. If you add another element, it will reallocate it to 4.

Here is a discussion of how PHP implements arrays:

http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html

Comment: Thanks !!. Now its clear it will not initialize 1449 values in the array !!